# php настроить время куки

Tags: php

Ставлю куки на 1 час в Php, через час они сбрасываются, и надо опять авторизироваться даже если сидишь на сайте, как сделать чтобы куки стирались через час бездействия?

Comment: так обновлйте их при каждом обращении

Comment: @splash58 это самое изящное решение?

Comment: Куки "стираются" браузером. Отправляются от сервера к браузеру только когда вы указываете заголовок `Set-Cookie` (например при помощи функции `setcookie()`. Если вы не будете отправлять этот заголовок, то браузер никогда не узнает о вашем намерении продлить время жизни куки. Другой вариант - периодически обновлять куку на стороне браузера пока открыта страница, но это уже JavaScript (и только если на куке нет флага httponly)

Comment: @SdafsFasafs А что плохого в обновлении куки. это просто небольшая строчка добавленная к ответу сервера.